# How to check whether a single character matches one of predetermined ones?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to make a calculator (details do not matter in this instance). I need to check whether a character used for operations matches one of the predetermined operations ( +, -, / and *) and separately for operations (neg, abs). I'm not very good at regex but here's what I tried:

```
if($operation =~ /[+\-*\/]/){
    ...
}elsif($operation =~ m/(neg|abs)/){
    ...
}
```

The program just skips through these when theoretically it should do the operations. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$operation =~ m{[+*/-]}` is cleaner imo. Less escaping of characters.

Comment: If stuff isn't matching, you should make sure the variable holds what you think it should.

Comment: Cab you give an example of value for `$operation` which fails to match when you think it should? Also the regex isn't anchored, so it will match strings like `"abc*def"` too. You likely want something like `^/[+\-*\/]$/`

Comment: Thanks to all participants! Put me on the right track. I wrote $operation as a simplified version of the actual code but indeed it was the main problem for the 'ifs' being skipped.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably put these in a hash then check with `exists`. It's even better if the hash value is the operation you want:

```
my $things = (
    '+' => sub ($n, $m) { $n + $m },
    ...
    'neg' => sub ($n) { -$n },
    'abs' => sub ($n) { abs($n) },
    };

if( exists $operations{$op} ) {
    $operations{$op}->(@operands);
    }
else { ... }
```